# mime type is supported when watch video first time but not supported the other times in package

Tags: xbox, media-source

I use `**hls.js**` to broadcast my live stream. 
When I watch a video on my package for xbox, I will check whether my browser is supporting MediaSource Extensions.
It would return true the first time, but false the others times.

here is the repository of Hls.js (https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#first-step-setup-and-support)

```
function getMediaSource() {
 if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
   return window.MediaSource || window.WebKitMediaSource
 }
}

function isSupported() {
 var mediaSource = getMediaSource();
  var isTypeSupported = mediaSource && typeof mediaSource.isTypeSupported === "function" && mediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"');

  var x =  !!isTypeSupported ;
  if (!x) {
     console.log("do not support!")
     console.log( typeof mediaSource.isTypeSupported)
     console.log(mediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"'))
     }

  return !!isTypeSupported
}



loadVideo(src: string) {
 if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    this.createVideoElement();
 } else {

   ... //show some message
 }

 ...
}
```

I expect the `Hls.isSupported()` is always true, but the actual output is false after the first time.

Comment: when I debug the package it will always return `true`.  So I use weinre to log some message. It would not appear if I open the debug window when I launch the app on xbox

Comment: Don't know xbox's UA nor HSL.js, but if it really returns true once but false after, that means something somewhere has modified your MediaSource constructor. Do you load some polyfill? You can check my assertion by doing somewhere in your checks `if(window.previousMediaSource) console.log("same:", window.previousMediaSource === MediaSource); else window.previousMediaSource = MediaSource;`.

Comment: Thanks, I have test it on xbox. It turn to be equal when I open the debug page and the ·Hls.isSupported()· return `true`. But when I close the debug page and do as I describe, the error appear.

Comment: Also there is a way can avoid the check:  use a varible to store the first result like ` if( isSupportHls || Hls.isSupported() ) `